# Python adding numbers for the tuples in the list with similar string

Tags: python, list, tuples, addition

How can I add the same tuples for the first parameter in object? for example, since there is 'appo' string with number 3 and 2, I want to add them up together into a tuple. How can I do it?

```
Initial:
nom = [('orange', 2), ('apple', 4), ('appo', 3), ('appo', 2)]

End:
nom = [('orange', 2), ('apple', 4), ('appo', 5)]
```

I'm still new to python. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def convert(nom):
    temp_dict = {}
    for key, value in nom:
        if key in temp_dict:
            temp_dict[key] += value
        else:
            temp_dict[key] = value

    result = []
    for key, value in nom:
        if key in temp_dict:
            result.append((key, temp_dict[key]))
            del temp_dict[key]
    return result

nom = [('orange', 2), ('apple', 4), ('appo', 3), ('appo', 2)]
nom = convert(nom)
print(nom)
```

Results in: `[('orange', 2), ('apple', 4), ('appo', 5)]`

Answer (score 1):

```
result = {}
for key,val in nom:
   try:
      result[key] += val
   except KeyError:
      result[key]=val

print result[key].items()
```

might do what you want ... if you arent worries about the order

you could also use `collections.defaultdict(int)` instead of try except

```
result = defaultdict(int)
for k,v in nom:
   result[k] += v
print result.items()
```

Answer (score 1):

The Counter class from collections is useful here.

```
from collections import Counter    
c = Counter()
nom = [('orange', 2), ('apple', 4), ('appo', 3), ('appo', 2)]
for n in nom: c[n[0]]+=n[1]
dict(c)
# {'apple': 4, 'appo': 5, 'orange': 2}
```

or as a function

```
from collections import Counter
def combine_tuples(tpls):
    c = Counter()
    for k, v in tpls:
        c[k] += v
    return c
    combine_tuples(nom)
    # Counter({'appo': 5, 'apple': 4, 'orange': 2})
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
class addTuples(object):
    def __init__(self, li):
        self.li = li
        self.k = []
        for i in li:
            if not hasattr(self, i[0]):
                setattr(self, i[0], i[1])
                self.k.append(i[0])
            else:
                setattr(self, i[0], getattr(self, i[0]) + i[1])
    def getTuples(self):
        nom = []
        for i in self.k:
            nom.append((i, getattr(self, i)))
        return nom
x = addTuples(nom)
x.getTuples()
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that over here you need *unique* values of the first parameter in the tuple in the list. This can be easily done by the `set` command. So for your `nom` variable, you have:

```
In [5]: for s in set( i[0] for i in nom  ): print s
orange
appo
apple
```

Then, you can simply iterate over the list and filter out the required values ...

```
In [10]: for s in set( i[0] for i in nom  ): print s, sum( m[1] for m in nom if m[0] == s )
orange 2
appo 5
apple 4
```

Of course, what you really want is to append the values in a temp array ...

```
In [12]: for s in set( i[0] for i in nom  ): temp.append( (s, sum( m[1] for m in nom if m[0] == s ))  )

In [13]: temp
Out[13]: [('orange', 2), ('appo', 5), ('apple', 4)]
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

There had to be a one-liner after all. Perhaps not the prettiest.

```
import itertools
nom = [('orange', 2), ('apple', 4), ('appo', 3), ('appo', 2)]
nom = [(k, sum(x[1] for x in g)) for k, g in itertools.groupby(nom, key=lambda x: x[0])]
print nom # [('orange', 2), ('apple', 4), ('appo', 5)]
```